# Perl too slow concurrent download with both HTTP::Async & Net::Async::HTTP

Tags: perl, http, asynchronous, concurrency, download

I'm trying to GET about 7 dozens of urls in parallel with scripts: the first is below, with HTTP::Async, and the second one is [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZegvN4vH), with Net::Async::HTTP.
The problem is that I'm getting pretty same timing results - about 8..14 seconds for all urls list. It's inacceptable slow compared to curl+xargs started from shell, which gets all in less than 3 seconds with 10-20 "threads".
For example, Devel::Timer in first script shows that max queue length is even less than 6 (`$queue->in_progress_count`<=5, `$queue->to_send_count`=0 allways). So, it's looks like foreach with $queue->add is executing too slow, and I don't know why.
Pretty same situation I got with Net::Async::HTTP (second script on pastebin), which is even slower than the first.

So, please, does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong? How can I get concurrent download speed at least compared to curl+xargs started from shell?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use utf8;
use strict;
use POSIX qw(ceil);
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Async;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep time);
use Devel::Timer;

#settings
use constant passwd => 'ultramegahypapassword';
use constant agent => 'supa agent dev.alpha';
use constant timeout => 10;
use constant slots => 10;
use constant debug => 1;

my @qids;
my @xmlz;
my $queue = HTTP::Async->new(slots => slots,max_request_time => 10, timeout => timeout, poll_interval => 0.0001);
my %responses;
my @urlz = (
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/products/4577',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/products/4653',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/products/4652',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/products/4571',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/products/4572',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/products/4666',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/products/4576',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/products/4574',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/products/4651',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[3294]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[3294]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/combinations/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4577]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4577]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4577]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/188',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/191',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/187',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/190',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/189',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4653]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4653]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/4577/12176',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4652]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4652]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/4653/12390',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/combinations/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4571]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4571]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4571]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/4652/12388',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/175',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/178',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/179',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/180',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/181',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/3294/8965',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/176',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/177',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/combinations/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4572]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4572]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4572]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/176',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/181',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/180',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/4571/12159',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/177',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/179',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/175',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/178',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4666]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/combinations/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4576]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4666]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4576]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4576]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/4572/12168',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/185',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/182',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/184',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/183',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/186',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/4666/12413',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/combinations/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4574]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4574]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4574]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/177',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/181',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/4576/12174',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/176',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/180',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/179',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/175',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/product_option_values/178',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/specific_prices/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4651]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/4574/12171',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/stock_availables/?display=full&filter[id_product]=[4651]',
'http://testpodarki.afghanet/api/images/products/4651/12387'
);

my $timer = Devel::Timer->new();


foreach my $el (@urlz) {
    my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $el);
    $request->header(User_Agent => agent);
    $request->authorization_basic(passwd,''); 
    push @qids,$queue->add($request);
    $timer->mark("pushed [$el], to_send=".$queue->to_send_count().", to_return=".$queue->to_return_count().", in_progress=".$queue->in_progress_count());
}

$timer->mark('requestz pushed');

while ($queue->in_progress_count) {
    usleep(2000);
    $queue->poke();
}

$timer->mark('requestz complited');

process_responses();


$timer->mark('responzez processed');

foreach my $q (@xmlz) {
#    print ">>>>>>".Dumper($q)."<<<<<<<<\n";
}

$timer->report();
print "\n\n";
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$queue`?

Comment: sorry, lost it. now fixed, thanks!

Comment: This code runs in just under four seconds on my system. The only difference is that I have used internet URLs that are accessible, as I get `503 Service Unavailable` from yours.

Comment: oh my glob. what is your OS and Perl? my is Debian 8.7 and Perl v5.20.2.
also, a run this on both hardware and virtual box with same results...
my urls are 503 cause them are from my intranet.

Comment: The `keep-alive` isn't always the friend of the web-scraper. Think what is the difference running `10 x curl` in parallel using `xargs -P...` and when you will use `Net::Async::HTTP` (which using the `keep-alive` by default) and the server is slow in response rate for the given connection.

Comment: @berrymorr: *"what is your OS and Perl?"* That was running Strawberry Perl v5.24.0 on WIndows 10 Professional. Can you show your timing output please?

Comment: @Borodin: I replaced my intranet urls with the internet ones to be in same circumstances with others: https://pastebin.com/VyhMEB3w
Here is timings: https://pastebin.com/kD5h2pQa

Comment: @jm666, maybe it's a lil bit dumby question, but how can I disable keep-alive with Net::Async::HTTP? Dunno how remove header, set by default

Comment: Also, this is not quite web-scrapper - this is some variation of REST client with GUI, and it's time critical to load data asap, so, I decided to use async load where it's possible. Typical set is two-three dozens of urls, about dozens kBs per url. Maybe it could be helpful - maybe I'm doing something wrong by design?..

Comment: @berrymorr added an "answer" for some demo, how me tried your script. Unfortunately, me is still an perl beginner so, i don't know :( how to disable the keep-alive.

Comment: Added a good bit to my answer, as I have by now tried  all I can think of with `HTTP::Async`.  (This included dropping `keep-alive` per @jm666 suggestion, but to no benefit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best results with [HTTP::Async](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Async/lib/HTTP/Async.pm) are well over 4 and up to over 5 seconds. As I understand this approach isn't required, and here is a simple forking example that takes a little over 2 and at most below 3 seconds.

It uses [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm) and [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/libwww-perl-6.24/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) for downloads.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Path::Tiny;    
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my @urls = @{ get_urls('https://pastebin.com/raw/VyhMEB3w') };

my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(60);  # max of 60 processes at a time
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
print "Downloading ", scalar @urls, " files.\n";

my $dir = 'downloaded_files/';
mkdir $dir if not -d $dir;
my $cnt = 0;   
foreach my $link (@urls) 
{
    my $file = "$dir/file_" . ++$cnt . '.txt';

    $pm->start and next;                        # child process

    # add code needed for actual pages (authorization etc)            
    my $response = $ua->get($link);        
    if ($response->is_success) {
        path($file)->spew_utf8($response->decoded_content);
    }
    else { warn $response->status_line }

    $pm->finish;                                # child exit
}
$pm->wait_all_children;

sub get_urls {
    my $resp = LWP::UserAgent->new->get($_[0]);
    return [ grep /^http:/, split /\s*'?,?\s*\n\s*'?/, $resp->decoded_content ];
};
```

The files are written using [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm). Its `path` builds an object and `spew` routines write the file.

For reference, the sequential downloads take around 26 seconds.

With the maximum number of processes set to 30 this takes over 4 seconds, and with 60 it is a little over 2 seconds, about the same as with (up to) 90. There are 70 urls in this test.

Tested at a 4-core laptop with a decent network connection. (Here the CPU isn't all that important.)  The tests were run repeatedly, at multiple times and on multiple days.

---

*A comparison with the approach from the question*

The best `HTTP::Async` results are slower than the above by around a factor of two. They are with 30-40 "slots" since for higher numbers the time goes up, what puzzles (me). The module uses `select` to multiplex, via [Net::HTTP::NB](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Net-HTTP-6.06/lib/Net/HTTP/NB.pm) (a non-blocking version of [Net::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Net-HTTP-6.06/lib/Net/HTTP.pm)). While `select` "does not scale well" this regards hundreds of sockets and I'd expect to be able to use more than 40 on this network bound problem. The simple forked approach does.

Also, `select` is considered to be a slow method to monitor sockets while forks don't even need that, as each process has its own url. (This may result in module's overhead when there are many connections?)  Fork's inherent overhead is fixed and dwarfed by network access. If we were after (many) hundreds of downloads the system may get strained by processes, but `select` wouldn't fare well either.

Finally, `select` based methods download strictly one file at a time, 
and the effect is seen by printing as requests are `add`ed -- we can *see* the delay. The forked downloads go in parallel (in this case all 70 at the same time  without a problem). Then there'll be a network or disk bottleneck but that is tiny in comparison to the gain.

**Update**: *I pushed this to double the number of sites and processes, saw no signs of OS/CPU strain, and retained the average speed.*

So I'd say, if you need to shave off every second use forks. But if this is not critical and there are other benefits of `HTTP::Async` (or such) then be content with (just a bit) longer downloads.

---

The `HTTP::Async` code that performs well ended up being simply

```
foreach my $link ( @urls ) {  
    $async->add( HTTP::Request->new(GET => $link) );
}    
while ( my $response = $async->wait_for_next_response ) { 
    # write file (or process otherwise)
}
```

I have also tried to tweak headers and timings. (This included dropping `keep-alive` as suggested, by `$request->header(Connection => 'close')`, to no effect.)

Comment: Also, I got my own below maybe lil bit faster (I wanna 2 believe at least), but you was the first, who posted acceptably fast working solution. On my VM your runs for about 4-5 sec, with first get for raw from pastebin.

Comment: You deserves a bounty, because you're the only who is really interested in the answering a question. Also, the  Parallel::ForkManager+LWP is simple and OK. Even if it isn't some speed-daemon. :) I will continue (if/when i'll be in the right mood :) and will post my findings.

Comment: @jm666 Thank you very much for the kind words :)  And for the attribution.  One main point here was that it's simple.  But the other one was speed -- I don't see how one can beat a straight-up fork.  Every page is pulled exactly as it comes, completely separately. If the files go to disk then there is no overhead to speak of, no time waisted. There are nicer forking frameworks of course, which may be better suited for integration with the rest of the job. I will add a little summary of posted approaches.  Thanks for calling the bounty, this ended up as a very informative page, I think.

Comment: @jm666  The critical part is that I saw absolutely no problem with the number of processes, no OS/CPU strain (on a four-core laptop).  It was really entertaining to watch that.  I am now curious and will run some extended tests, with hundreds of links.  Will add a comment on that if it is interesting.

Comment: I'm interested in the scenario what the OP said in a comment: _this is some variation of REST client, and it's time critical to load data asap, ..... Typical set is two-three dozens of urls, about dozens kBs per url._ . So, no static files, no internet - but **one server** (maybe on high-speed local net), and how to get fastest possible data-loading into the app - e.g. even without saving the data to local HDD. Here plays big role not only the "client part" but also the "server" part (e.g. number of workers and such). On the original question he uses only the `testpodarki.afghanet` server...

Comment: @jm666 Ah, OK, thank you for the explanation.  I will look into that.  (It also goes along with another thing I'm checking out now.)

Answer (score 4):

For explaining my comment. I was curious, because never used the `Net::Async::HTTP` before, wanted to try your script locally. So, created this minimalist Plack `app.psgi`:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use Plack::Builder;
use Plack::Request;
use Plack::Response;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);

my $app = sub {
    my $env = shift;
    my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);

    my($ms,$id) = $req->path_info =~ /(\d+)/g;
    $ms //= 0;
    $id //= "NOID";

    #fake some processing slowness
    usleep($ms);

    my $res = Plack::Response->new(200);
    $res->content_type('text/plain');
    $res->body( "req# $id served by PID $$ fakewait: $ms\n");
    return $res->finalize;
};

builder {
#    enable "Auth::Basic", authenticator => \&auth;
    $app;
};

#sub auth { return $_[0] eq 'me' && $_[1] eq 'me' }
```

The server understand URL's in a form `GET /sleep_time/reqID`, where

- the sleep time is in microseconds for the `usleep` - and the server sleep the given time before responds. E.g. it fakes some "processing time".
- id - any number for req-identifying...

E.g. requesting `GET /1000000/1`, the server will sleep 1second before responds. In response is included the `PID` of the responding process.

In one terminal window run the above using `Starman` preforkimg server with default `20` workers.

```
plackup -s Starman
```

And in the another window the results using `xargs`:

```
time seq 20 | xargs -n1 -P10 -I% curl http://localhost:5000/1000000/%
```

so, sending 20 requests, where each response tooks `1s` processing time.

```
req# 1 served by PID 28163 fakewait: 1000000
req# 2 served by PID 28161 fakewait: 1000000
req# 3 served by PID 28162 fakewait: 1000000
req# 4 served by PID 28160 fakewait: 1000000
req# 5 served by PID 28159 fakewait: 1000000
...
real    0m4,032s
user    0m0,092s
sys     0m0,074s
```

So, 20 requests = 4 seconds. It is visible, that the reponding `PID`'s are different - e.g the repsonse is sent by different worker.

Now using your script `async.pl` (slightly shortened/modified):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Request;
use IO::Async::Loop;
use Net::Async::HTTP;
use Future::Utils qw(fmap_void);

my $sleep = $ARGV[0] // 0;
my $numreq = $ARGV[1] // 20;

my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new();

my $http = Net::Async::HTTP->new( timeout => 10, max_connections_per_host => 0, pipeline => 0, ip_tos => 0x10 );
$loop->add( $http );

my $future = fmap_void {
    (my  $url ) = @_;
    my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
    #$request->authorization_basic('me','me');
    $http->do_request( request => $request )
        ->on_done( sub {
            my $response = shift;
            my($body) = $response->content =~ s/\n.*//sr;
            print "$url [", $response->code, "] --> $body\n";
        } )
        ->on_fail( sub {
            my $failure = shift;
            print "$url failed: $failure\n";
        } );
} foreach => [map { "http://localhost:5000/$sleep/$_" } (1 .. $numreq)];
$loop->await( $future );
```

command

```
time perl async.pl 1000000 20
```

result

```
http://localhost:5000/1000000/1 [200] --> req# 1 served by PID 28160 fakewait: 1000000
http://localhost:5000/1000000/2 [200] --> req# 2 served by PID 28160 fakewait: 1000000
http://localhost:5000/1000000/3 [200] --> req# 3 served by PID 28160 fakewait: 1000000
http://localhost:5000/1000000/4 [200] --> req# 4 served by PID 28160 fakewait: 1000000
http://localhost:5000/1000000/5 [200] --> req# 5 served by PID 28160 fakewait: 1000000
http://localhost:5000/1000000/6 [200] --> req# 6 served by PID 28160 fakewait: 1000000
...
real    0m20,309s
user    0m0,183s
sys     0m0,053s
```

Same 20 requests = 20 seconds, and **each** request is served by the same `PID`. Like pure sequential processing. :(

This *probably* because the requests reusing the connection (eg. the keep-alive).

Finally - unfortunately, as i told - i haven't any experience with the module, so haven't idea how to force the module to do-not-reuse the opened connection.

Comment: So, I finally installed Wireshark! ;)
And found that **HTTP::Async sends _Connection: close_**, and **Net::Async::HTTP sends _Connection: keep-alive_**. Important thing is that I used `$http->do_request( request => $request, headers => ['Connection' => 'close'] )` with _Net::Async::HTTP_, just [as documented](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Net-Async-HTTP-0.41/lib/Net/Async/HTTP.pm#$response_=_$http-%3Edo_request(_%args_)-%3Eget), but without any result. _HTTP::Async_ still 2 times faster than _Net::Async::HTTP_.
So common case goes jolly bad show!..

Comment: So, now I'm going to try [WWW::Curl::Multi](http://search.cpan.org/~crisb/WWW-Curl-3.02/lib/WWW/Curl/Multi.pm) and [Furl](http://search.cpan.org/~syohex/Furl-3.09/lib/Furl.pm), but the last one has no concurrency and needs reinventing my own bicycle. Btw, looks like there is some useful info [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=901638).

Comment: @berrymorr when you got an solution which works for you, please, add it as an answer here. (You can answer, your own question). :) It could be great help for other users.

Comment: ofcourse!)
So, some news: I tried _Net::Async::HTTP_ on win7/active perl v5.24.1 and got the same illy concurrent results. Also I tried _HTTP::Async_, but it just shows me empy console and perl never returns. Other libs them can not install.
Also tried [Net::Curl::Multi](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1161866) on Debian - got even 30s for internet urls list from above.
I'm about desperation, wtf?!

Comment: At last, good news: looks like that [Furl with threads](https://pastebin.com/teAhXPmK) is fast enough, but the code is not parallel downloader, it's something like _siege_ in Perl. Also, mommy told me do not use threads with Perl.
So, it's too early to celebrate, but it's the first real concurrent something.
Hope some later I'll post the solution.

Comment: This question deserves more attention. :) Going to add some bounty.

Comment: This is a whole truck-load of tools to look into! :)  Didn't wrap my mind around it yet but it is nteresting.  Do you recommend `Plack` for regular use (over the competing frameworks)?

Comment: @zdim In short: no. :) But, you should to use any [PSGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/PSGI/PSGI.pm) compliant framework. The `Plack` is "only" the reference implementation of the PSGI. On the CPAN you will find (too) many :) Plack based frameworks - which one - is a personal taste. My favorite is `Poet/Mason`. Others love `Dancer2`. Even the big-gun Catalyst is PSGI compatible. Of course, usually the PSGI-app is behind `nginx` - it is good for serving static files and acting as an SSL endpoint.

Comment: @zdim Here me used the very simple Plack-app (runnung using Starman) only because wanted an simple reference server for testing. Also remember, me is only perl-beginner, better to ask  someone with more knowledge. :)

Comment: Oh ... thank you for the explanation and for the example! Something to work on for me :)

Comment: Some "beginner" :)  Dumped a web server here, just so :)  Thank you for the example, plenty to work through.

Comment: @zdim me not kidding with the beginner. Having serious problems to understand some of perl answers in SO.  The answers here are really good source for learning. But, thanx :)

Answer (score 4):

So, finally got working sample ([full script](https://pastebin.com/S0vapZwA)). It uses `Furl` and `fork_call` from `AnyEvent::Util`. This example returnes in ~3 secs, what is good enough. If you need to use basic HTTP auth, just use URI with creds like this: `username:password@hostdomain.org/path?param1=val1&param2=val2`. You better add `use EV;` before using `AnyEvent` because EV is the fastest.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Devel::Timer;
use Furl;
use EV;
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Util 'fork_call';

#get full script
my @urls = (...);


sub fetch {
    my $url = shift;
    my $furl = Furl::HTTP->new(agent => 'Furl/0.31',timeout => 3);
    print "start $url\n";
    my ($ver, $code, $msg, $headers, $body) = $furl->get($url);
    my $size = length $body;
    print "finished $url, $size bytes\n";
    return ($code, $msg, $headers, $body);
}

my %resps;

my $timer = Devel::Timer->new();
$timer->mark('foreach');
$AnyEvent::Util::MAX_FORKS = 20;
my $cv = AE::cv;
foreach my $url (@urls) {
    $timer->mark('next foreach');
    $cv->begin;
    fork_call {
        print "getting $url... ";
        my ($code, $msg, $headers, $body)=fetch($url);
        print "[$code]\n";
        return ($url, $code, $msg, $headers, $body);
        }
        sub {
            print "adding 2 %resps\n";
            my ($url, $code, $msg, $headers, $body)=@_;
            $resps{$url}->{'code'}=$code;
            $resps{$url}->{'msg'}=$msg;
            $resps{$url}->{'headers'}=$headers;
            $resps{$url}->{'body'}=$body;
            $cv->end;
        };
}
$cv->recv;
$timer->mark('end');

print "\nall data is ready, press <ENTER>:";
<STDIN>;
print Dumper(%resps);
print "\n<PRESS ENTER>to print timer report\n";
<STDIN>;
$timer->report();
sleep(3);
```

Comment: Good to have an example of an event-based approach.

Comment: I have [a script to check URLs using AnyEvent::HTTP](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/urlheadinfo) - that is fast, too, although I never measured it.

Answer (score 2):

Async will be slower than parallel downloading: the async code will yield to other calls only while waiting for a response, but downloading happens sequentially in a single process, while the curl+xargs will work 100% (well, almost 100%, and as long as you don't saturate the cores) in parallel, same as when using forked workers.

please, google for "concurrency is not parallelism"

Comment: A nice and simple explanation.  I'd like to add, there's more chance to saturate the I/O subsystem here.  (I fork over a hundred processes in extended tests on four cores of an oldish laptop and see no signs of CPU/OS strain.)

Comment: you could try threads with the master+workers pattern and Thread::Queue (or fork processes and use Message::Passing :) ): 

the master starts a number of workers, then loads the URL list while the workers fetch URLs from the queue and use one of the *::Async* modules to download the URLs concurrently   .                             

The best of both worlds :)    .                                        

I would use Coro, but that limits you to perl 5.20, not working with newer versions if I remember right