# Parallel processing using AnyEvent (Any) module with custom function

Tags: perl, asynchronous, anyevent

I am trying to use the [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emlehmann/AnyEvent-7.14/lib/AnyEvent.pm) module to fetch some information of several web pages in parallel.

In Example: [Fetching several web pages in parallel using AnyEvent](https://perlmaven.com/fetching-several-web-pages-in-parallel-using-anyevent)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::HTTP;

my @urls = qw(
    https://perlmaven.com/
    https://cn.perlmaven.com/
    https://br.perlmaven.com/
);

my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;

foreach my $url (@urls) {
    print "Start $url\n";
    $cv->begin;
    http_get $url, sub {
        my ($html) = @_;
        print "$url received, Size: " . length($html) . "\n";
        $cv->end;
    };
}

print 'Before the event-loop' . "\n";
$cv->recv;
print 'Finish' . "\n";
```

This is working fine but now I want to run some custom subroutine instead of using [AnyEvent::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emlehmann/AnyEvent-HTTP-2.22/HTTP.pm) **http_get**

**Custom subroutine:**

```
sub http_get{
    my $url = shift;
    my $cmd = q{curl -s --head } . $url . q{ | grep 'Content-Length:' | awk '{print $2}'};
    my $length = qx{$cmd};
    return $length;
}
```

**Question:**
How do I modify this custom http_get to work with [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emlehmann/AnyEvent-7.14/lib/AnyEvent.pm)?

My main requirement is that I want to call some methods inside the for loop and want to change existing behaviour by calling it asynchronously by using any module with compatible perl version 5.8.8:

```
my $db_rows = $self->_scan_data(); # Get Data from DB
for my $listener ( @{ $self->listener } ) { # Loop on listener. # runs 2 time loop.
    if ( $listener->can('compute_scan_data') ) { # Check if listener is available.
        $listener->compute_scan_data($db_rows); # Want to run this asynchronously
    }
}
```

**Perl Version Information:**

```
[09:20:22 user@server ~ # perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 8) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=2.6.18-53.1.14.el5pae, archname=i386-linux-thread-multi
    uname='linux builder16.centos.org 2.6.18-53.1.14.el5pae #1 smp wed mar 5 12:07:47 est 2008 i686 athlon i386 gnulinux '
    config_args='-des -Doptimize=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -Dversion=5.8.8 -Dmyhostname=localhost -Dperladmin=user@localhost -Dcc=gcc -Dcf_by=Red Hat, Inc. -Dinstallprefix=/usr -Dprefix=/usr -Darchname=i386-linux -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dsiteprefix=/usr -Duseshrplib -Dusethreads -Duseithreads -Duselargefiles -Dd_dosuid -Dd_semctl_semun -Di_db -Ui_ndbm -Di_gdbm -Di_shadow -Di_syslog -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseperlio -Dinstallusrbinperl=n -Ubincompat5005 -Uversiononly -Dpager=/usr/bin/less -isr -Dd_gethostent_r_proto -Ud_endhostent_r_proto -Ud_sethostent_r_proto -Ud_endprotoent_r_proto -Ud_setprotoent_r_proto -Ud_endservent_r_proto -Ud_setservent_r_proto -Dinc_version_list=5.8.7 5.8.6 5.8.5 -Dscriptdir=/usr/bin'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    usethreads=define use5005threads=undef useithreads=define usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define d_sfio=undef uselargefiles=define usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=undef use64bitall=undef uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm',
    optimize='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/gdbm'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
    ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=4, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='gcc', ldflags =' -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /lib /usr/lib
    libs=-lresolv -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
    perllibs=-lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
    libc=/lib/libc-2.5.so, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so
    gnulibc_version='2.5'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/CORE'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -L/usr/local/lib'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
                        PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_PERLIO USE_REENTRANT_API
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Sep 17 2008 13:37:09
  @INC:
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
    .
```

Comment: Maybe you could try [`AnyEvent::Fork`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::Fork)?

Comment: There are a few options that would suit better, I am not a big fun of doing syscalls but you could try to use the http_head method or create an event loop using forks, or overide the http_get method with your desired subroutine.

Comment: Does it have to be `AnyEvent`? Also: Perl 5.8.8 is very very old. You should consider upgrading. It's very nearly 10 years out of date.

Comment: Isn't the `sub { ... }` in `get_http` where you code your custom functionality?  Why do you want to replace `http_get` itself?

Comment: See [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43024722/4653379) for a related problem and various options.